# Launch Image On Main View Controller Background Stretched

Tags: iphone

I want to display the launching image(640x960) of my app on my main view controller. I added UIImageView to  the view and set the image to be the launch image. However, the image is stretched.

I want to be able to make the top 40px of the image to be underneath the status bar so that no streching will be needed. In other words, I want to make the image fill up the whole iphone screen, and that the status bar will simply be on top of the image.
(I think this is what happens when the launch image is initially shown when the app launches.)

How can this be done?

Another option is to use Photoshop to create the image by cutting off  40 pixels in height of the image, so it will be 640x920, and then there wouldn't be any problem, but I don't want to create another image, as I think there should be a way to do this from code.

EDIT: Found the solution, read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

First of all, as I thought, when the app is being launched the launched image is shown, while the status bar crops the top 20pt of the image.

In order to achieve this in your view controller, simply:

1. Add UIImageView and choose the image you want
2. In the Attributes inspector choose Mode: Scale to Fill
3. In the Size Inspector, X=0, Y=-20, Width=320, Height=480

And Volia, there you go!

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the view properties to not be either fill or fit; and set the dimensions of the UIImageView to the exact dimensions of the image.

Also, your frame should be 0, 20, 320, 460, as the status bar is 20 px high.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the status bar height. The mode is 'Scale to Fill'. In size inspector I changed the values to 0, 20, 320, 460 - but now it doesn't fill the whole screen. Must I set the frame property programatically?

Comment: As I said, don't use scale to fill if you don't want your image resized.  You could also try setting the frame to 0,0,320,460.

Comment: oh, sorry, I was sure you meant to set it to these values. Let me try it now.

Comment: Further comment: the choice of frame depends on the sizing behaviour of your controller's view.